# Physical interpretation of the following stress-energy tensor : $T^{\mu\nu}=X^\mu X^\nu$

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have come across the following stress-energy tensor and  I was wondering if anyone know of a physical system this could correspond to?

$$
T^{\mu\nu}=\pmatrix{(X^0)^2 & X^0X^1 & X^0X^2&X^0X^3 \\ X^1X^0&(X^1)^2&X^1X^2&X^1X^3\\X^2X^0&X^2X^1&(X^2)^2&X^2X^3\\X^3X^0& X^3X^1&X^3X^2&(X^3)^2}
$$

where $X^0,X^1,X^2$ and $X^3$ are fields, functions of $\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}$.

It is obtained by taking a vector of fields, such as

$$
\mathbf{v}:=\pmatrix{X^0[x,y,z,t]\\X^1[x,y,z,t]\\X^2[x,y,z,t]\\X^3[x,y,z,t]}
$$

And then taking product of the vector with its transpose:

$$
\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T=\pmatrix{(X^0)^2 & X^0X^1 & X^0X^2&X^0X^3 \\ X^1X^0&(X^1)^2&X^1X^2&X^1X^3\\X^2X^0&X^2X^1&(X^2)^2&X^2X^3\\X^3X^0& X^3X^1&X^3X^2&(X^3)^2}
$$

Comment: Have come across where?

Comment: @Qmechanic I have obtained it by adding a vector inner product to gravity: 
$\int ( R\sqrt{|\det g|} + \mathbf{v}^Tg^{\mu\nu}\mathbf{v} ) d^4x$

Answer (score 4):

If this stress–energy tensor corresponds to some realistic matter then  for every observer (characterized by the timelike 4-velocity $W_\mu$) the local energy density must be non-negative ($T^{νμ} W_ν W_μ\ge 0$) and the local energy flow vector ($F^μ=T^{μν}W_ν$) must be non-spacelike (formally  we would say that stress–energy tensor must satisfy the *dominant energy condition*). This would mean that the field $X^μ$ is everywhere either timelike or null.  We would discuss those possibilites (timelike and null $X^μ$) separately. We would also assume that $X^μ$ is future pointing (otherwise we could just change its sign).

If $X^μ$ is *timelike*, then the stress-energy tensor has only one nonzero (and positive) eigenvalue which would be the energy density in the comoving frame. We   can interpret such stress–energy tensor as that of a pressureless  (dust) matter. We could then define 4-velocity field of this dust $\mathbf{u}$ , and energy density in comoving frame $\rho$ through vector field $\mathbf{X}$:
$$u^μ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{X^ν\phantom{|}\! X_ν}} X^μ, \qquad \rho = X^ν X_ν ,$$
assuming “mostly minus” metric signature.

Using these quantities the stress–energy tensor could be written in a possibly more familiar form:
$$
T^{μν}=\rho\, u^μ u^ν.
$$
In the comoving frame it would take particularly simple form: $T^μ_ν=\rho \mathop{\mathrm{diag}}(1,0,0,0)$.

If $X^μ$ is *null* then the stress–energy tensor would correspond to a *null dust matter* and may be seen as either a limiting case of dust matter or pure radiation matter and could also arise as a stress energy tensor  of null Maxwell field. The vector $X^μ$ would then be its principal null direction.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that I diagonalize the tensor? If I diagonalize $T^{\mu\nu}$, I get $\pmatrix{0 &0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&(X_0)^2+(X_1)^2+(X_2)^2+(X_3)^2}$. Then, this is to be interpreted as a dust tensor? Is this correct?

Comment: If the metric tensor has timelike component as $g_{44}$ then yes. Usually though timelike coordinate is chosen to have index 0.

Comment: Why do you say that $X$ cannot be spacelike? For an observer with four-velocity $U^\mu$ the energy density is $T_{\mu\nu} U^\mu U^\nu = (X_\mu U^\mu)^2$, which is positive no matter what.

Comment: @Javier: If $X$ is spacelike, we can choose $U$ so that $U_μX^μ=0$. Then the energy density would be zero. We would have nonzero stress with zero energy. But you do have a point. This would violate not the WEC but the DEC.